# Error when trying to update Craft

Tags: php, error, json

I'm pretty new to CraftCMS and am trying to install updates for a client. I am getting this error and I don't really know what it means. Any help of brief explanation for this would be appreciated.

> Error: The "https://asset-packagist.org/packages.json" file could not
> be downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini (https://
> wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
> failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found) Output:
> Loading composer repositories with package information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `php --ini` in your server environment, it should tells you where the `.ini` files are getting loaded.

Then set

```
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

Comment: ^ - I'll add this is noted in the docs here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/requirements.html#optional-php-methods-and-configurations